# using resource dictionary as central collection of all images

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, resourcedictionary

i have a project with a lot of assemblies (> 100). many of those assemblies have subfolders like "images". many wpf-windows/user-controls for example have a "\images\close.png". that means that i have many "close.png" pictures instead of just a single one.

now i want to create a central place for all images/resources. what i did:

- created a new class-libary/assembly called "a.b.c.d.e.Core.Resources"
- added a resourcedictionary called "ImageDictionary.xaml"
- created a subfolder "Images"
- copied my images to this subfolder. for example "a.b.c.d.e.Core.Resources\images\close.png"
- setting the built property of the image to "resource"
- declared the image in the "ImageDictionary.xaml" like this "< ImageSource x:Key="Image_close">close.png< /ImageSource>"
- using the dictionary in the wpf window where i want to use the "close.png" image like this

  < Window.Resources>
      < ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/a.b.c.d.e.Core.Resources;component/Images/ImageDictionary.xaml"/>
  < /Window.Resources >
- trying to use the image declared in the central resource dictionary "ImageDictionary.xaml" like this < Button>< Image Source="{StaticResource Image_close}">< /Image>< /Button>

in the designer mode of VS the image is beeing displayed but when i start the project and open my wpf window i get an error like

"{"The File or Assembly \"a.b.c.d.e.Core.Resources, Culture=neutral\" or one of its dependencys can't be found. The system can't find the given file.":"a.b.c.d.c.e.Resources, Culture=neutral"} (i translated the error message from german to english :) )

Does anyone have any idea what i did wrong and why i can't get the central resourcedictionary getting to work properly? Thanks for any ideas!!!

Greetings from Germany

edit:
i also have a reference to "a.b.c.d.e.Core.Resources" in the assembly where my wpf window is

edit 2:
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Message=RowNumber "7" and RowPosition "10" of "Setting the Property "System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source" caused an exception".

Comment: I'm assuming that `a.b.c.d.` is meant as example for much longer names?

Comment: Yes but its not extremely long. "aa.bbb.cc.ddddd.eeee.Core.Resources". thats the length of the namespace

Comment: Do you have an app.xaml in each project with this central Resource Dictionary declared under 'MergedDictionaries' so it knows to find it?

Comment: No, i only have one single App.xaml in the default start project

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the first idea I have is, that the file cannot be found because of the [maximum path length limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) of the `WinApi`. I'm not sure about it, because I don't know anything about the internals of the resource loading mechanism.

Please try to start the program from a shorter path. Perhaps, it'll solve the problem.

**EDIT**

Just an idea, is your `ImageDictionary.xaml` declared as resource? If not, you should set its build step to "resource".

**EDIT2**

Next idea. Please empty the `ImageDictionary.xaml` by commenting out the elements. Uncomment the dictionary element by element. Perhaps, you'll find the reason for your problem, this way.

Comment: i just created a fresh sample project with small namespaces/project paths but it doesnt work either.

Comment: @SLimke: Pls refer to my edit. Seems to be silly, but it's the only idea I have. :o)

Comment: ImageDictionary.xaml has buildprocess set to "page" at the moment

Comment: Did you try to set it to "resource"? If I recall correctly, I also had to deals with such an error, although I don't know what the content of the error message was.

Comment: yes i tried it with "resource" but it didn't work. i get the same exception

Comment: @SLimke Hmm, ok I don't have any other idea. I'm sorry. Perhaps a little code (the dictionary) would help.

Comment: Even if i have a completely empty ImageDictionary.xaml i get the exception

Comment: i think i got some new info: the assembly in which my wpf window is including the resourcedictionary is a classlibrary.

there seems to be a problem when including a resourcedictionary in wpf windows in a classlibrary. when i setup a sample project in which my wpf window is in an assembly with the type of a "windows-application" it works pretty fine

Comment: i uploaded my sample project:
http://www.daten-hoster.de/file/details/417780/Project1.zip

i hope you can reproduce my problem and perhaps you have any ideas for me to fix it.